# db2 INSERT query returns error code unique constraint violation

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, db2

I am using db2 as a database. before inserting the record into table  I am fetching available INSERT ID by

```
$pgm = i5_program_prepare("ACSCOMOBJ/PROC", $params);
$retval = i5_program_call($pgm, $iparams, $oparams);
```

In $retval I am getting unique id 6017088(I checked into database record with this id not exist )  I am trying to execute insert query using

```
INSERT INTO Table_name (OHNUMB, OKLNNO) VALUES (6017088, 1)
```

result of this query is error message 23505  which is for unique constraint violation.

is it problem related to db2 database? how can I fix?

Comment: Not really enough info in the question to answer. Adding the table schema to the question may help. Is there any trigger on the table? Does the error happen every time or just intermittently? It looks like first getting a free id, then inserting may cause a race condition if there are multiple accesses.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : error not produces every time and I did't found any trigger on that table

Comment: Then it seems you may have a race condition. You're getting a free id, someone else gets the same id (since it's still free) and inserts, and your insert fails due to the id no longer being free.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: But I checked in to database. this Id is already free. and my same database schema is used for both staging and production.

Comment: What is the relevance of the `same database schema is used for both staging and production`? It seems that it's supposed to be useful information for us, but I can't see how it helps us to know it. Is there a detail in it that should clarify your situation? Also, what is the actual complete error message, what platform is DB2 installed on and what is the DB2 version?

Comment: Check out this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151009/